# Sync Video Capture Between Android Devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth, synchronization, timing, mediarecorder

I'm working on a project to capture and upload video from two Android devices (a Glass and a tablet), which communicate with each other via Bluetooth. My sync, upload, and capture process (using one device to control the other) works well, but I'm having trouble getting the recordings (via MediaRecorder) to stay in sync. Currently the process is:

- Send start message from Glass and start 5 second countdown on Glass
- On start message, start 5 second countdown on tablet
- On countdown end, begin recording on both devices
- On stop signal sent from Glass, stop both recordings and upload

Note that this assumes that the countdowns will start at exactly the same time and that MediaRecorder will take exactly as long to prepare and start on both devices. This naive approach does roughly sync (less than 500ms difference between files), but I know there has to be a better way. I know part of the issue is that passing and acting on the Bluetooth messages is introducing latency, but I'm not sure how to resolve this. I've tried adding additional sync and start messages to compensate for the countdown lag, but the overhead those add seem to make the problem worse. What's the best way to closely synchronize timing of media recording (or I guess other intensive activities)? I know some lag is inevitable but getting this down to around 100ms drift would be acceptable.

Comment: i would suggest instead sending the timestamp in 5 seconds and have them both prepare the recording as soon as the countdown starts, then set them both record at exactly the timestamp that was sent, not after 5 seconds, so they will both record at the same time no matter how long it took for the message to get there

Comment: Thanks Tomer, I had to refactor my code a bit to do this but that's a good approach that worked well for me.